# What is the correct puntuation or grammer for this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

It may be that I can't combine this question and sentence.

> Do you want a car, insurance, gas and maintenance can be $100 a month not counting the cost of saving for a car or a car payment.<

Should it be written,*  >Do you want a car? Insurance, gas and maintenance, can be $100 a month not counting the cost of saving for a car or a car payment.<
For some reason I want them combined in one sentence.
Thanks, Mikek

* oh my, another example of question before a sentence. Help me!

Comment: It's not clear to me why "a question before a sentence" is a problem. Please edit to explain more about what you're trying to do and why you have concerns about this option.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you want a car, insurance, gas and maintenance can be $100 a month not counting the cost of saving for a car or a car payment.

The above example does not work as the question is lost in the combined construction.  Your suggested version with two sentences needs to be refined:

> Do you want a car?  Insurance, gas and maintenance can be $100 a month, not counting the cost of [the] car.

To have a combined sentence, you may consider the following, with **still** used for emphasis:

> Do you [still] want a car [when] insurance, gas and maintenance can be $100 a month, not counting the cost of [the] car?

Answer (score 0):

The version with two sentences, "Do you want a car? Insurance, gas and maintenance, can be $100 a month not counting the cost of saving for a car or a car payment," is grammatically correct. It still has a logic flaw: "Insurance, gas, and maintenance" does not include  "the cost of saving for a car or a car payment", so it makes no sense to say these costs excluding saving, etc. That would be like saying, "All horses, except for those that are rabbits, are ..."

"Do you want a car, insurance, gas, and maintenance ..." sounds like it's introducing a list: Do you want a car and insurance and gas and maintenance? But then the sentence veers off and we must re-interpret the list.

In this case one could figure out that you mean "Do you want a car?", and the list is expenses to be considered. But in other cases it might not be clear which of the items separated by commas are the things the person might want versus part of the reasons not to get it. Like, "Do you want a marriage, children and a house can be expensive." Does the speaker mean, "Do you want a marriage and children? A house can be expensive." Or "Do you want a marriage? Children and a house can be expensive."

Or to put it another way, you need to separate the question from the reasons that you suppose might influence an answer.

What I presume you mean is, "Do you really want to buy a car, considering insurance, gas, and maintenance can be $100 a month, plus there's the cost of saving for the down payment and monthly payments on the loan?"

Comment: "Do you really want to buy a car, considering insurance, gas, and maintenance can be $100 a month, plus there's the cost of saving for the down payment and monthly payments on the loan." So then, asking a question without a question mark, and having just the comma separation is proper syntax.

Comment: @MikeKnowlton That solution works too, though you probably want a semicolon after "month." And there's the question of whether the sentences need to be combined at all; what's so wrong with short sentences? Or is the goal to ensure that there is no question mark? Are you doing this for a test or assignment? To make this question answerable, please edit to explain a bit more about your goals.

Comment: @MikeKnowlton Whoops, no. Sorry, that was a mistake, there should have been a question mark. It is, by the way, a long and awkward sentence. If I realy wanted to say that I'd probably break it up.